# spymemcached (Java Memcached Client)

Tags: java, memcached

Is there a way to collect the memcached stats using this API (**spymemcached**)?

I know there are tools like cacti to collect information on Memcached Server. But I would like to collect, say, memory usage by each item I have put into the server--the total no. of items in the same category, etc... ***more importantly, the bytes used by individual pieces.***

Answer (score 1):

[getStats()](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.html#getStats%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

please try xmemcached. 
http://code.google.com/p/xmemcached/

as far as i know, xmemcached support JMX based statistics.but i'm not sure how detail it is.